# Windows Serverと仮想化ツールの不具合について

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vmware

現在以下の仮想化ツールを日常的に使用しています。

1. Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.12
2. VMware Workstation 15.5.5 Player
3. VMware ESXi 5.5
4. VMware ESXi 6.7

これらの上にWindows Server 2016、または2019を構築し、2本の仮想ディスクで記憶域プールを作成してから仮想ディスクを作成し、ミラーリングを組みたいのですが、2019の方は1と2のどちらの仮想化ツールを用いても1本しかディスクが認識されません。

また2016の方は2では同じ症状が出るのですが、1ではちゃんと2本とも認識されて、やりたいことが実現できる状況です。

自分なりに問題を切り分けますと、2019は1と2のどちらのツールを用いてもダメなので、おそらくツール側がOSに完全に対応できていないのかな？と考えていますが、同じような症状を経験された方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

また、OSのバージョンや仮想化ツールとの相性云々以前に、何か対応策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら是非教えて頂きたく思います。

ちなみに3と4のツールは個人で自宅練習用に使うのは面倒臭すぎるので試していません。

何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

VirtualBox に関して言えば、ドキュメントでゲストOSとしてサポートを明言されているのは Windows Server 2012 までのようです。
これより新しいバージョンのOSを入れようとした時には、運よく動くかもしれないし、何らかの不具合がある可能性もあります。

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes

他のツールに関しても同様に、リリースノート等にサポート状況の情報が掲載されているかと思うので、まずはそれらの情報を参照することをおすすめします。